# Yosemite wifi problems

Tags: osx-yosemite, wifi-configuration

I'm experiencing strange WiFi behavior on my mac book pro. Everytime I lock my computer (even for a minute) it disconnects it from our office WiFi and I have to manually reconnect it. Sometimes it even kills all the programs and completely logs me out. At first I thought these bugs are happening because I've upgraded. And I decided to do clean install, I've completely formatted the disk and reinstalled the system. The problem still persists. Can anyone suggest if there's something I could try in order to fix that?

Comment: Have you installed the 10.10.1 update?

Comment: yes, all current updates are up.